# AWK power set implementation

Tags: shell, unix, awk, powerset

[This page](http://catonmat.net/blog/set-operations-in-unix-shell-simplified) provides a [power set](http://wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set) implementation in shell, and here is my take on it:

```
pa() {
  if [ "$#" = 0 ]
  then echo
  else (
    shift
    pa "$@"
  ) | while read qu
    do printf '%s %s\n%s\n' "$1" "$qu" "$qu"
    done
  fi
}
pa x y z
```

I thought it was interesting that the author of the above page made this comment:

> no nice AWK solution. You are welcome to email me one: <his email>

Can this not be done in AWK, or does the shell just do a better job here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is another AWK approach:

```
echo a b c | awk '{for(i=0;i<2^NF;i++) {
                     for(j=0;j<NF;j++)
                        if(and(i,(2^j))) printf "%s ",$(j+1)
                     print ""}}'

a
b
a b
c
a c
b c
a b c
```

If your AWK doesn't have the `and()` function, replace it with `int(i/(2^j))%2`.

Comment: You should put this in Code Golf power set implementation in here: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/9045/shortest-power-set-implementation ... unless you can make it even shorter... :D

Comment: thanks for the suggestion.  I added there http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/103948/17581 .  You can drop the `i=0` initialization from the first loop.

Comment: Elegant and concise. Worth noting that each output line but the 1st will have a trailing space. _GNU_ Awk is the only major Awk implementation that supports `and()`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution adapted from [Rosetta Code](//rosettacode.org/wiki/Power_set#AWK):

```
function al(br, ch, de) {
  while (br) {
    ch--
    if (br % 2)
      de = de $(sprintf("%c", 49 + ch)) FS
    br = int(br / 2)
  }
  return de
}
{
  for (ec = 0; ec <= 2 ^ NF - 1; ec++) {
    print al(ec, NF)
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
echo x y z | power-set.awk
```

[Example](//github.com/svnpenn/a/blob/d8d528d/etc/power-set.awk)

Answer (score 0):

In GNU AWK (due to `and`, `lshift` and *the way of* `split`:)

```
$ cat program.awk
BEGIN {
    n=split(s,a,"")
    for(i=1;i<2^n;i++) {
        for(j=1;j<=n;j++)
            if(and(lshift(1,(j-1)),i))
                printf "%s", a[j]
        print ""
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
$ awk -v s="abc" -f program.awk
a
b
ab
c
ac
bc
abc
```

Comment: ... which turned out essentially the same as @karakfa's solution even to the variable names. I need new friends and variables.

Comment: @StevenPenny: More accurately, using `""` as `split()`'s 3rd (_fs_) argument in order to split a string into individual characters is _not POSIX-compliant_, but GNU Awk, BSD Awk, and Mawk all support it.